# Infinitesimal generator of brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

It the literature we see that the infinitesimal generator of Brownian motion is $\frac{1}{2} \Delta$.
However, when we search about the generator of the Brownian motion on the (unit) sphere, we see that the brownian motion is constructed to have the generator of $\frac{1}{2} \Delta_{S^2}$. Why the language is different in these two cases? In $\mathbb R^n$, the generator is calculated from the process. On sphere, the process is defined such that it has generator $\frac{1}{2} \Delta_{S^2}$. How can it be explained?

Comment: How do you define "Brownian motion on the sphere"?

Comment: @user6247850 there are different methods in the literature. I don't know about the details of the constructions.

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to know more about the details of the constructions before asking on here.

Comment: @user6247850 The question is not about the construction methods. The question is about the different language used there.

Comment: For the record. Opening sentence of OP's first MSE post yesterday: "For a student not familiar with stochastics, can someone explain what is exactly Brownian motion?" @Kevin welcome to MSE but pleaee study more patiently the introductory literature.

Comment: @KurtG. You got this out of context. I wrote after that sentence my main question. The question was not related to basic definitions everyone can read from and introductory books. If you cannot understand the question (and the source of the confusion led to a question), you don't have to react!

Answer (score 2):

The difference comes from the different spaces they exist in.

Standard Brownian motion is on flat, Euclidean space and its generator is the Laplacian $\frac{1}{2}\Delta$ (Laplacian is a differential operator that measures the divergence of the gradient of a function).

When we move to a curved space like the sphere the Laplacian is adjusted to $\Delta_{s^2}$ to account for the curvature, and the generator of the Brownian motion on the sphere becomes $\frac{1}{2}\Delta_{s^2}$.

The generator of the Brownian motion whether in flat space or on a sphere represents the underlying dynamics of the motion. The difference in the generators comes from the difference in the spaces where the motions are defined.

I believe the proof for the generator of standard Brownian motion is relatively straightforward. It is derived from the definition of Brownian motion and the properties of the Laplacian operator.

In the 1D case it can be showed that $Af(x) := \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{\mathbb{E}^x[f(B_t)] - f(x)}{t} = \frac{1}{2}f''(x)$.

Taylor expansion about $f(x)$:

\begin{align} \mathbb{E}^x[f(B_t)] &\approx \mathbb{E}^x[ f(x) + (B_t-x) f'(x) + \frac{1}{2}(B_t-x)^2 f''(x)]\ &= f(x) + \mathbb{E}^x[B_t-x] f'(x) + \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}^x[(B_t-x)^2] f''(x)\ &= f(x) + \frac{t}{2} f''(x) \end{align}

This result shows that the generator of a standard Brownian motion is indeed $1/2 \Delta$

For the Brownian motion on a sphere, the proof is more involved and requires the use of stochastic differential equations (SDEs) in spherical coordinates.

The generator of Brownian motion on $S^2$ (with the round metric) is $\frac12\Delta$, where
$\Delta$ is the Laplacian on $S^2$, in spherical coordinates
$$\Delta = \frac{1}{\sin\theta}\partial_{\theta}(\sin\theta\cdot\partial_{\theta})+\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}\partial_{\varphi}^2.$$

The Brownian motion on $S^2$ is then defined by the following system of SDEs:

\begin{align} d\theta_t&=\frac12\cot\theta_t dt+\sin\varphi_t dB_t^{(1)}-\cos\varphi_t dB_t^{(2)},\ d\varphi_t&=\cot\theta_t\left(\cos\varphi_t dB_t^{(1)}+\sin\varphi_t dB_t^{(2)}\right)-dB_t^{(3)}. \end{align}

Using Itô's lemma, one can then check that for a $C^2$ function $f(\theta_t,\varphi_t)$:

$$df(\theta_t,\varphi_t) = \frac12\Delta f(\theta_t,\varphi_t) dt + ... dB_t^{(1)}+ ... dB_t^{(2)}+ ... dB_t^{(3)}$$

$dt$ term is $\frac{1}{2}\Delta f(\theta_t,\varphi_t)$ which shows that the generator of the process is indeed $\frac{1}{2}\Delta$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how can it be explained that in one space, we calculate B from A, and in different space we assume B to construct A?

Comment: Its due to the fundamental difference in their geometries.In flat space we have a well defined rules for calculus. This is y we can calculate B(the generator) from A(the Brownian motion) in this case.for a sphere we don't have the same direct rules. more challenging game. Instead we take an approach that is more intuitive and physically motivated:we define what we want the generator to be (in this case we define it 2 be the Laplacian on the sphere,adjusted 4 the sphere's curvature) and then construct the Brownian motion that has this generator.This is y we assume B to construct A  in this case